# Android 11-14/Error in BluetoothSocket: java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth

I am developing an android app on kotlin to connect via bluetooth to odb2 and I get an error:

```
java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
                                                                                                        at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readAll(BluetoothSocket.java:816)
                                                                                                        at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readInt(BluetoothSocket.java:830)
                                                                                                        at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:442)
```

This is my connection code:
I do it according to the example from the documentation https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth#ConnectAsAClient

```
class ConnectThread(private val device: BluetoothDevice,private val  bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter?) : Thread() {
    private val uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB")
    private val mmSocket: BluetoothSocket? by lazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE) {
        device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid)
    }

    override fun run() {
        bluetoothAdapter?.cancelDiscovery()

        mmSocket?.use { socket ->
            socket.connect()
        }
    }

    fun cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket?.close()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Log.e("TAG", "Could not close the client socket", e)
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest

```
   <!--BLUETOOTH PERMISSION-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="false"/>

    <!--LOCATION PERMISSION-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
```

I know that such questions have already been asked, but the solutions that were in the answers do not help me.

- I tried different static UUIDs (fa87c0d0-afac-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66, 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB, 5cb6b8e2-b944-44b3-b806-a92d4587123c)
- I tried to generate a new UUID every time.
- I tried using different UUIDs for different types of devices:
  (UUID: 0000xxxx-0000-1000-8000- 00805f9b34fb
  i xxxx Status Mode
  0 110 a N.A.
  1 1105 Serial Port Protocol (SPP)
  2 1106 File transfer (FTP)
  3 1116 N.A.
  4 112d Remote SIM mode
  5 112 phonebook request
  6 1112 N.A.
  7 111f N.A.
  8 1132 Message access request)
- I tried different bluetooth devices (TV, pc, soundbar, headphones, other phones).
- I tried to run it on different android phones (api lvl 29-34).
- I tried to use device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord and createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord

I get this error every time. The connection is started in a separate thread. I see in bluetooth devices that there is a connection for a few seconds, after which it knocks out this error.